# how to set MSG_MORE in boost asio for unix domain sockets?

Tags: boost-asio

I am using boost asio with unix domain sockets, I am confused on how to set the `MSG_MORE` while sending the message. I did a grep in the boost code and did not find any references to `MSG_MORE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload for whatever `send` socket member function you are using that accepts a `flags` argument.  For example, here is one of the overloads for [`local::datagram_protocol::socket::async_send()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send/overload2.html):

```cpp
template<
    typename ConstBufferSequence,
    typename WriteHandler>
void async_send(
    const ConstBufferSequence & buffers,
    socket_base::message_flags flags,
    WriteHandler handler);
```

The `flags` argument is a [bitmask](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/message_flags.html) that specifies how the send call is to be made.  As these are socket specific, the free functions will not provide overloads that accepts these flags.